# JQuery trigger("click") to select detail page custom button to launch Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, jquery

Is it possible to programmatically select a custom button with Jquery, so that when it is selected a Visualforce page is launched? This doesn't seem to be working for me and I'm not getting any errors in the console. It's saying that the button was selected, but the VF page associated with the custom button doesn't launch.

```
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function(){
    j$("input[name='new_related_case']").on("click", function(e){
            console.log("New Related Case was selected");
     });

    j$(".detailList tr td").each(function(){
       var caseOrgin = j$(this).text();
        if(caseOrgin == "Web"){
            console.log("Case Orgin: Web");
            j$("input[name='new_related_case']").trigger("click");
      }  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The each function (as you have it written) only runs when the document is ready.

Try changing it to this (if you want it to run each time the input is clicked:

```
j$("input[name='new_related_case']").on("click", function(e){
            console.log("New Related Case was selected");
        j$(".detailList tr td").each(function(){
           var caseOrgin = j$(this).text();
             if(caseOrgin == "Web"){
               console.log("Case Orgin: Web");
               //other stuff here                   
         }
     });
```

Comment: @VanAlfredo By doing that all you did is run the code as the page loads (and possibly break the other click code as the element may not exist as it is ran) so leave the .ready function as it was.....It still will not run the .each function on a click of a button. Did you happen to try what was posted as the answer? You are going to have to modify it a bit to meet your needs as your scope is not entirely clear.

Comment: I see what you mean. I did try the code you provided, but I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for. I want it so that When caseOrgin is equal to "Web" the browser simulates a user clicking on the custom button, so the associated VF page will launch.

Comment: @VanAlfredo - It will do what you want with the proper selectors, I cannot say what they should be as your page is not posted....The pattern in the answer should be correct, you will need to figure out the selectors

Comment: I do appreciate your help. I tried using j$(".detailList tr td:contains('Web')") as well, but the j$("input[name='new_related_case']").trigger("click"); still dosen't do anything.

Comment: are you even getting to that point in the code. does your console.log in the place of the trigger.("click") actually log?

Comment: yes sir. I get it logged in the console.

Comment: The why are you trying to trigger the "click" if you are using what I have above you are ALREADY in the click. Since you are in the click, and the origin = web, execute the function you want to to do....

Comment: I dont want to be in the click. Essentially, I'm trying to create a custom event that will fire the click when the origin is Web.

Comment: You show code for a click, you ask that when an item is selected (assumed you meant clicked) that you wanted something to happen, now you don't want it to be a click but something else (unclear on what that is). I hope you can take something from this answer and conversation and make it work.

Comment: I have something that is working. It's saying that the button is being "clicked" in the console, but the popup isn't showing. I do appreciate your time.